# Determining the unmatched portion of a string using a regex in Python

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a string "a foobar" and I use "^a\s*" to match "a ".

Is there a way to easily get "foobar" returned? (What was NOT matched)

I want to use a regex to look for a *command word* and also use the regex to remove the command word from the string.

I know how to do this using something like:

```
mystring[:regexobj.start()] + email[regexobj.end():]
```

But this falls apart if I have multiple matches.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give example input and output? How will you get multiple matches? Do you want an array of the unmatched parts?

Comment: string = "87 foo 87 bar"

regex = "87\s*"  <-- this has multiple matches.

I want to get "foo bar" returned somehow.

I don't want an array, just a single string.  I know how to separate a string based on regexs but that requires knowing where an expression will occur (token order) in the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = "87 foo 87 bar"
r = re.compile(r"87\s*")
s = r.sub('', s)
print s
```

Result:

```
foo bar
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I knew it there was a simple way.  Thanks!

Comment: You can also merge `r = re.compile(); s = r.sub()` into `s = re.sub()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("87\s*", "", "87 foo 87 bar")
'foo bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of splitting or separating, maybe you can use re.sub and substitute a blank, empty string ("") whenever you find the pattern. For example...

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("^a\s*", "","a foobar")
'foobar''
>>> re.sub("a\s*", "","a foobar a foobar")
'foobr foobr'
>>> re.sub("87\s*", "","87 foo 87 bar")
'foo bar'
```

Answer (score 2):

from http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split

```
>>> re.split('(\W+)', 'Words, words, words.')
['Words', ', ', 'words', ', ', 'words', '.', '']
```

so your example would be

```
>>> re.split(r'(^a\s*)', "a foobar")
['', 'a ', 'foobar']
```

at which point you can separate the odd items (your match) from the even items (the rest).

```
>>> l = re.split(r'(^a\s*)', "a foobar")
>>> l[1::2] # matching strings
['a ']
>>> l[::2] # non-matching strings
['', 'foobar']
```

This has the advantage over re.sub in that you can tell, when, where, and how many matches were found.