# how to return first unmatch character using regular expression in python

Tags: regex, python-2.7

this is my code of python to match list of strings

```
import re
strLIST=['MCA2014PDICT','MCA2014FLOWM','MCA2014AFISRT','MCA1014PDICT']
pattern='MCA2014[P|F]{1}[A-Z]{4}'
for str in strlist:
    match=re.search(str,pattern)
    if match:
        print "congrats your",str,"matched"
    else:
        print str," not matched"
```

here i am not getting because of which character or digit my string not matched.
i want first character or digit which causes string gets unmatched.I want reason for getting string unmatched.

here the first string:MCA2014PDICT should get passed

but string:MCA2014AFISRT should get false and it should return the character

A:because of this string unmatched.because at 7th position character should be either P or F and in our string its A.

for string:MCA1014PDICT it shuld return 1. because at 4th position it should be 2.
1:it should be 2.*

please help me to get first character or digit because of that string unmatched using python regular expression

Comment: `strlist` is capitalized different from `strLIST` ... Is this a copy/paste error or is it like that in your code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determining the unmatched portion of a string using a regex in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195340/determining-the-unmatched-portion-of-a-string-using-a-regex-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You have misused the re.search function, the correct syntax is `re.search(pattern, string)` you have it completely the other way around....