# How to save unused parts of a string as a regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am working with a file with book citation information. Such as title, author, publisher, font size in this format:

```
Austen (Hy. T.)—lectures on passages in
Genesis. 8vo., 6s HATCHARD, Feb. 20
Austen (Jane)—Emma. (Standard Novels.
No. 25.) i2mo., 6s BENTLEY, 32
```

If I am searching through this line by line and extracting out the author and publisher, etc with regular expressions, is there a way to save or match the parts of the string that are not searched for?

Clarification:
I am specifically referring to if I have a few tags, such as one for author one of publisher and one for title and there is extra information in between these tags, how can I get all those "unused" parts?

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195340/determining-the-unmatched-portion-of-a-string-using-a-regex-in-python

other people have had this problem before

Comment: `parts of the string that are not searched for` What do you mean by this? If you want to find secondary information, just include it in the regex, capture what you want. Secondary info can be used as pseudo-anchors that allow fine tuning the search.

Comment: If you have a regexp like `(foo).*(bar)`, you can get the unused part by putting another capture group around it: `(foo)(.*)(bar)`

Comment: If you have saved the parts that were matched you could just use the `replace` command on the original string to replace the matched parts with an empty string (`""`). The resulting string will be what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried using the replace method, but it doesn't seem to actually replace anything. This is a portion of my code:                                    pub=re.search(r'%s' %reg_publisher_start, line)
        u5=re.sub(r'%s' %reg_publisher_start, "", line)
     
        if pub:

            print "   Publisher: ", pub.group()

            print "unused" + u5.group()